# Structures, pointers, and c++

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

```
 #include<string>
 #include<iostream>
 #include<fstream>
 #include<string>

 using namespace std;
 const int INVALID_INDEX = -1;
 // Here are the two structures
 struct DrinkItem
 {
  int id;
  string name;
  double price;
  int number_of_drinks;
  int drinks_purchased;
  };
  struct DrinkMachine
  {
  int version_number;
  int number_of_drinkitem;
  DrinkItem * ptr1;
  int current_location;
  };

 // I am creating a pointer to the Drink machine structure

 DrinkMachine* create()
 {
DrinkMachine*ptr = new DrinkMachine;
(*ptr).version_number = 1;
ifstream sample("drink_machine.txt");
if (sample.fail())
{

    delete ptr;
    return nullptr;

}
else
{

    int number;
    double number1;
    string name;
    sample >> number;
    (*ptr).number_of_drinkitem = number;
    (*ptr).version_number = 1;
    (*ptr).current_location = INVALID_INDEX;

    // Above I created all the values for the members and below I am creati
    //    ng a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of DrinkItem   
    //  structure
    //    that will be nested inside the DrinkMachine structure. 

    ptr->ptr1 = new DrinkItem[number];
    int count1 = number;
     // Here I am using a for loop to initialize all the values for the 
     //    nested structure
    for (int count = 1; count <= count1; count++)
    {

        (((*ptr).ptr1) + (count - 1))->id = count;
        sample >> name;
        (((*ptr).ptr1) + (count - 1))->name = name;
        sample >> number1;
        (((*ptr).ptr1) + (count - 1))->price = number1;
        sample >> number;
        (((*ptr).ptr1) + (count - 1))->number_of_drinks = number;
        (ptr->ptr1)[count - 1].drinks_purchased = 0;

    }


    sample.close();
    return ptr;
}


}
```

Above is the program's function the program compiles but it crashes when I 
    declare a function call. All the values are being read to in the right
    direction. The error comes in
    through the debugger where it marks the address ptr is pointing to, but I 
    don't know what it exactly means. Also there might be better ways to do this
    but I have to do it this one way so using this logic I need to find out 
    what's wrong. Thanks for your time. Also the values are being read through
    an input file but you don't have to worry about that as everything is stored
     in the right location as in I checked for all the values using the for 
     loop. The error has to do with the location ptr is pointing to which 
     doesn't make any sense as it is dynamically allocated.

Comment: Don't write `(*ptr).ptr1`, it looks horrible. Use `ptr->ptr1` instead.

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake on my part

Comment: You can (should) replace every `(*ptr).stuff` (where `stuff` is a member name) with `ptr->stuff` ex. in `(*ptr).number_of_drinkitem`, `(*ptr).version_number`, many `(*ptr).ptr1`s later on, etc.

Comment: Yeah I understand but that isn't what's causing the program to crash though

Comment: NM i figured it out thx for the time